# How to pass tags of existing resources to cloud watch alarm in CFT in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to add a CloudWatch alarm over multiple instances in my AWS account based on the instance tags.

For example, I have 4 instances running with tags `Name=DEV`, `APP=WebServer`.

I am new to AWS CloudFormation templates, so I am not sure how to add the tags in the CloudWatch alarm's `dimensions` property. Can I attach a single alarm to multiple instances by referring to them by tags when I create the instances?

Here's a snippet from my template.

```
CPUAlarm:
  Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
  Properties:
    AlarmDescription: CPUtilization
    AlarmActions: "SNS TOPIC ARN"
    MetricName: CPUUtilization
    Namespace: AWS/EC2
    Statistic: Average
    Period: '60'
    EvaluationPeriods: '2'
    Threshold: '80'
    ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
    Dimensions:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the instances via CFN template, you can parameterize the tags and use the same parameters in your cloudwatch alarm resource